# How to make a regex group become more greedy

Tags: regex

So given that I have rows like the following:

```
SAMSUNG 840 EVO MZ-7TE500BW 2.5" 500GB SATA III TLC
SAMSUNG 840 Pro Series MZ-7PD512BW 2.5" 512GB SATA III MLC
SAMSUNG 840 Pro Series MZ-7PD256BW 2.5" 256GB SATA III MLC
```

I want to transform them such that the size part goes to the end, like this:

```
SAMSUNG 840 EVO MZ-7TE500BW 2.5" SATA III TLC = 500GB
```

I'm trying the following regex, but unfortunately the middle group captures only the very last digit of the size (e.g. `0GB` in the above example).

```
\n(.*)(\d+GB)(.*)
```

How can I change it such that the middle group captures all digits?

Note: I'm using VS2013's Find/Replace.

Comment: What you need is to make the `*` **less** greedy.

Comment: @dotNET really easy... [`(.*?)(\d+GB)(.*)`](http://regex101.com/r/dR9gQ3/1)

Comment: Perhaps look at some documentation?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks HamZa. @OliverCharlesworth: Your suggestion was correct. I'll happy to accept if post it as answer.